# Looping select box

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I've form with date field and select box and there's and add row, once i clicked add row it'll add a new row with the same field.

the problem is , the select box doesn't working.

here's my view code :

```
<div class="panel panel-inverse" data-sortable-id="ui-general-1">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-heading-btn">
        <a id="add-row-btn" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"> Add new row</a>
    </div>
    <h4 class="panel-title">Interview Track | Form</h4> 
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="interviewTrack-boxes">
        <div class="row interviewTrack-content">
             <?php $index = 0; ?> 
            {!! Form::hidden('interviewTracks['.$index.'][id]', null)!!}    
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Track Date</label>
                            {!! Form::text('interviewTracks['.$index.'][track_date]', null, ['id' => 'remarks', 'class' => 'form-control'])!!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Status</label>
                            {!! Form::select('interviewTracks['.$index.'][status]', $interviewTrackList, null, ['id' => 'status', 'class' => 'form-control'])!!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Outcome</label>
                            {!! Form::select('interviewTracks['.$index.'][outcome]', $outcomeList, null, ['id' => 'outcome', 'class' => 'form-control'])!!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Remarks</label>
                            {!! Form::text('interviewTracks['.$index.'][remarks]', null, ['id' => 'remarks', 'class' => 'form-control'])!!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php $index++; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here's my jquery to add new row so far :

```
var $index = parseInt($('.interviewTrack-content').last().attr('id')) + 1; 
    $('#add-row-btn').on('click', function(e) { 

        var hrEle = $('<hr>'); 
        $('.interviewTrack-boxes').append(hrEle); 
        $('.interviewTrack-content:last .form-group input[type="text"]').each(function(index) { 
            var eleName = $(this)[0].name; 
            var id = parseInt($('.interviewTrack-content').last().attr('id')); 
            eleName.replace('['+id+']', '[1]'); 
            $(this).attr('name', eleName.replace('['+id+']', '['+$index+']')); 
        });  
        var clone = $('.interviewTrack-content').last().clone(); 
        clone.appendTo($('.interviewTrack-boxes')); 
        $('.interviewTrack-content').last().attr('id', $index); 
        $index++; 
    });
```

any idea ?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by not working.

Comment: I can't use select box, I click it and it doesn't show the option.

Comment: @Terminus and also date field, im using datetimepicker, but the new row datetimepicker doesn't working also.

Comment: Is any error shown at the console?

Comment: Do the 2d element indexes (e.g. *track_date*, *status*, etc) need to be string literals, or are they constants? - e.g. `{!! Form::text('interviewTracks['.$index.'][\'track_date\']', null, ['id' => 'remarks', 'class' => 'form-control'])!!}`

Comment: @JoseRojas so far there's no error at console.

Comment: @SamOnela isn't working,

Comment: have you tried to inpect element of the select to check if it has an option tag inside it on run time?

Comment: I've tried inpect element but seems nothing error.

Comment: When you add the new row is not setting the values in the selects in that new row?

Comment: @JoseRojas no default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed `<div class="row interviewTrack-content">` to `<div class="row interviewTrack-content" id="<?php echo $index ?>">`

```
<div class="panel panel-inverse" data-sortable-id="ui-general-1">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-heading-btn">
            <a id="add-row-btn" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"> Add new row</a>
        </div>
        <h4 class="panel-title">Interview Track | Form</h4> 
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="interviewTrack-boxes">
           <?php $index = 0; ?> 
            <div class="row interviewTrack-content" id="<?php echo $index ?>"> 
                {!! Form::hidden('interviewTracks['.$index.'][id]', null)!!}    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Track Date</label>
                                {!! Form::text('interviewTracks['.$index.'][track_date]', null, ['id' => 'remarks', 'class' => 'form-control'])!!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Status</label>
                                {!! Form::select('interviewTracks['.$index.'][status]', $interviewTrackList, null, ['id' => 'status', 'class' => 'form-control'])!!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Outcome</label>
                                {!! Form::select('interviewTracks['.$index.'][outcome]', $outcomeList, null, ['id' => 'outcome', 'class' => 'form-control'])!!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Remarks</label>
                                {!! Form::text('interviewTracks['.$index.'][remarks]', null, ['id' => 'remarks', 'class' => 'form-control'])!!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php $index++; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

jquery

added

```
$('.interviewTrack-content:last .form-group select[class="form-control"]').each(function(select) {
        var eleName = $(this)[0].name;
        console.log(eleName);
        var id = parseInt($('.interviewTrack-content').last().attr('id'));
        eleName.replace('['+id+']', '[1]');
        console.log(id);
        $(this).attr('name', eleName.replace('['+id+']', '['+$index+']'));
    });
```

and changed $index to index in jquery code.below is final jquery.

```
var index = parseInt($('.interviewTrack-content').last().attr('id')) + 1;
$('#add-row-btn').on('click', function(e) {

    var hrEle = $('<hr>');
    $('.interviewTrack-boxes').append(hrEle);
    $('.interviewTrack-content:last .form-group input[type="text"]').each(function(index) {
        var eleName = $(this)[0].name;

        var id = parseInt($('.interviewTrack-content').last().attr('id'));
        eleName.replace('['+id+']', '[1]');
        console.log(id);
        $(this).attr('name', eleName.replace('['+id+']', '['+index+']'));
    });
    $('.interviewTrack-content:last .form-group select[class="form-control"]').each(function(select) {
        var eleName = $(this)[0].name;
        console.log(eleName);
        var id = parseInt($('.interviewTrack-content').last().attr('id'));
        eleName.replace('['+id+']', '[1]');
        console.log(id);
        $(this).attr('name', eleName.replace('['+id+']', '['+index+']'));
    });
    $('.interviewTrack-content:last .form-group select[class="form-control"]').each(function(select) {
        var eleName = $(this)[0].name;
        console.log(eleName);
        var id = parseInt($('.interviewTrack-content').last().attr('id'));
        eleName.replace('['+id+']', '[1]');
        console.log(id);
        $(this).attr('name', eleName.replace('['+id+']', '['+index+']'));
    });
    var clone = $('.interviewTrack-content').last().clone();
    clone.appendTo($('.interviewTrack-boxes'));
    $('.interviewTrack-content').last().attr('id', index);
    index++;
});
```

Comment: Undefined variable: id. id="<?php echo $id ?>".

Comment: did you move <?php $index = 0; ?>  tage above the interviewTrack-content tag

Comment: Im trying this <div class="row interviewTrack-content" id="<?php $index = 0; ?> "> , there's no error, but not working.

Comment: try now? i made some fix, now each of your select and name will have unique names

Comment: it's working when I put this $('select').select2('destroy');
even with ur first code that u gave to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128019/discussion-between-andrew-vanusi-and-mohamed-athif).

Comment: With the first code.  Your select names were no unique i think. Means form submission can be tricky

Comment: Can you summarize the changes to the code, above the code snippets?